# скачать pywin32 на buildozer

Tags: python, android, изображения, excel, pywin32

Мне нужна помощь в скачивании `pywin32`.Я пишу приложение для android, которое создает `.xlsx` файл и преобразует его в изображение. Но вот проблема, чтоб его преобразовать нужна библиотека `pywin32`. Когда я ее вписываю в `buildozer.spec`, появляется ошибка `No matching distribution found for pywin32`.

Есть ли способ скачать `pywin32`? Может можно преобразовать другим способом?

Comment: Так это модуль только под винду.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/excel2img/

Comment: так эта библиотека excel2img просит pywin32

Comment: Ну хз тогда ...